# Error en el listado de archivos

Tags: shell

estoy creando un script .sh en el que al principio del script creo un listado en una ruta, y en ese listado quiero que solo aparezca el archivo xml.

La línea en concreto la tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
ls $VARIABLE_RUTA/*.xml > $VARIABLE_TXT/GNV_files_$CURRENT_CYCLE.txt
```

De esta forma en el txt me guarda la ruta completa con el script.
Mi pregunta es, saben decirme como puedo hacer para que solo me muestre el xml?

Comment: Puedes quitar la ruta con `basename`, intenta con `for a in $VARIABLE_RUTA/*.xml; do basename $a >> $VARIABLE_TXT/GNV_files_$CURRENT_CYCLE.txt; done`.